# How to report a value from Mapper to the Driver program in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a hadoop program in which I would like to report a value back to the driver at the end of the mapper. So, in the driver I multiple values, each from a mapper ans then I want to get the maximum between the value. I'm coding it using Counter and here is the code I have:

```
protected void cleanup(Context context){        
    ....
    context.getCounter("TimeStamps", "Max").setValue(value);
}
```

and in the driver I have

```
CounterGroup counters = job.getCounters().getGroup("TimeStamps");
    Iterator<Counter> iter = counters.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Counter c = iter.next();            
    }
```

However only value is reported back (instead of multiple values). What should I do so that each mapper report a separate value and I can get them all in the driver?

Comment: You can actually pass the job id and get all the counters in your job driver, once the map reduce is completed.

Comment: I have given an answer for this question. Check if it suits your requirements

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju: Could you explain it by some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this (though, I feel it is not a clean way).

When you are emitting a counter in the mapper, you can get the task attempt id and prefix the counter name with this.

For e.g. in the `map()` method of WordCount program, for every word encountered, I emitted:

```
context.getCounter("ME", context.getTaskAttemptID() + ":MY_TOTAL").increment(1);
```

Above, `ME` is counter group. The counter name is combination of `Task Attempt ID` and `MY_TOTAL`.

For e.g. the map task attempt IDs are usually of the form: `task_1450681906391_0024_m_000000_0` (`m_000000_0` is for first mapper in the job).

So, your counter name for this mapper will be: `task_1450681906391_0024_m_000000_0:MY_TOTAL`.

Similarly counter names for different mappers will be:

```
Mapper 2 => task_1450681906391_0024_m_000001_0:MY_TOTAL
Mapper 3 => task_1450681906391_0024_m_000002_0:MY_TOTAL
Mapper 4 => task_1450681906391_0024_m_000003_0:MY_TOTAL
```

Now, in the driver, I added the following code, after setting `Job::waitForCompletion(true)`:

```
job.waitForCompletion(true);

CounterGroup counters = job.getCounters().getGroup("ME");
Iterator<Counter> iter = counters.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Counter c = iter.next();
    System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue());
}
```

I ran the word count program for 1 GB of data, which spawned 7 mappers. After the successful execution of the program, I got the following output:

```
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000000_0:MY_TOTAL 9318964
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000001_0:MY_TOTAL 9068018
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000002_0:MY_TOTAL 9241336
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000003_0:MY_TOTAL 9182102
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000004_0:MY_TOTAL 8948100
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000005_0:MY_TOTAL 8992634
attempt_1450681906391_0024_m_000006_0:MY_TOTAL 8564646
```

You can see that, counters for different mappers are emitted separately. You can easily parse out the mappers and get the counter for each mapper as below:

```
Mapper 1 => MY_TOTAL 9318964
Mapper 2 => MY_TOTAL 9068018
Mapper 3 => MY_TOTAL 9241336
Mapper 4 => MY_TOTAL 9182102
Mapper 5 => MY_TOTAL 8948100
Mapper 6 => MY_TOTAL 8992634
Mapper 7 => MY_TOTAL 8564646
```